# R create index depending on other variable for large data sets

Tags: r, bigdata, large-files

This is a simple task in a small data set, but I have millions of observations, so I need a very fast alternative.

I would like to create an index identifying pairs of alpha-beta. Alpha-betas are in pairs always. It is easy to create a loop with this but I have found that it would take so long that R stops. Anyone know a fast solution for large datasets to create the right column below?

```
id  var1 var2   index
A   2   alpha   1
A   3   beta    1
B   5   alpha   2
B   6   beta    2
B   4   alpha   3
B   7   beta    3
C   3   alpha   4
C   5   beta    4
D   4   alpha   5
D   8   beta    5
```

Data sample:

```
df <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), var1 = c(2L, 
3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L), var2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("alpha", "beta"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", 
"var1", "var2"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the columns are already ordered

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, indx:= cumsum(var2=='alpha')]
df
#    id var1  var2 indx
#1:  A    2 alpha    1
#2:  A    3  beta    1
#3:  B    5 alpha    2
#4:  B    6  beta    2
#5:  B    4 alpha    3
#6:  B    7  beta    3
#7:  C    3 alpha    4
#8:  C    5  beta    4
#9:  D    4 alpha    5
#10: D    8  beta    5
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use repetition. Downside is that var2 must only consists of Alpha-Beta pairs, any occurrence of a missing value or anything else and this method may fail:

```
df$index <- rep(1:(length(df$var2)/2), each = 2)
```